# Reading buffer asynchronously over TCPIP client connection

Tags: c#, asyncsocket, tcp

I wrote a client which connect to a medical machine over TCP/IP. That machine send me XML files based on internal triggered event. I have to catch those XML and store on filesystem.
I used a class which provide asynchronous connection and works fine except for few things: when I check the written files I noticed that they contains two xml separated by a null value (coded as 0X00).
So I put a kind of filter on buffer but the problem remains. Basically I have to break my buffer when I detect the end of an XML file.

This is the code that provide async read:

```
try
{
    NetworkStream networkStream = this.client.GetStream();                
    int read = networkStream.EndRead(asyncResult);

    if (read == 0)
    {
        if (this.Disconnected != null)
            this.Disconnected(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    byte[] buffer = asyncResult.AsyncState as byte[];
    if (buffer != null)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[read];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, data, 0, read);
        networkStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, this.ClientReadCallback, buffer);
        content.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.TakeWhile((b, index) => index <= read).Where(b => b != 0x00).ToArray()));

        // Store the file
        string machineId = StoreFile(content.ToString());

        counter++;
        if (this.DataRead != null)
            this.DataRead(this, new DataReadEventArgs(data));
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.Log(ex.Message);
    if (this.ClientReadException != null)
        this.ClientReadException(this, new ExceptionEventArgs(ex));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're cutting off the start of the second XML document, but then continuing to read. The next read will not have a 0, so you will write its contents.

```
Read: XML1
Read: XML1 \0 XML2 <-- you cut this XML2 off
Read: XML2 <-- but then continue reading here.
```

Comment: You mean that I've to omit the check against null value (0x00) which is the separator between the two files?

Comment: Your `buffer.TakeWhile((b, index) => index <= read).Where(b => b != 0x00).ToArray()` bit stops appending XML2 _for that single read_. You start a new read after that, and when it completes it'll continue writing.

Comment: You need to check if the buffer contains a `0`, and then stop performing reads.

Comment: So, right after `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.TakeWhile((b, index) => index <= read).Where(b => b != 0x00).ToArray())` I would check if my buffer is zero length?